# ParticleSystem as DoTween tween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, dotween

I want to call ParticleSystem.play inside DoTween Sequence.
Somefing like:

```
DOTween.Sequence()
        .Append(_transform.DOScale(0, 0))
        .Append(ParticleSystem.Play())
```

I was looking for ways to convert and tried to write a wrapper class, but nothing happened. Help me please.

Comment: I haven't used DoTween for a while and I don't have a possibility to check right now, but I think you could do something like `.AppendCallback(ParticleSystem.Play)`, or `.AppendCallback(() => ParticleSystem.Play())`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution)

```
private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;

DOTween.Sequence().
        Append(DOTween.To(PlayParticle, 0, 1, _particleSystem.main.duration))

private void PlayParticle(float f)
{
if(!_particleSystem.isPlaying)
_particleSystem.Play();
}
```